# How can I open a file found by File::Find from inside the wanted function?

Tags: windows, perl, file-find

I have code like below. If I open the file `$File::Find::name` (in this case it is `./tmp/tmp.h`) in my `search` function (called by `File::Find::find`), it says "cannot open the file ./tmp/tmp.h reason = No such file or directory at temp.pl line 36,  line 98."

If I open the file directly in another function, I am able open the file. 
Can somebody tell me the reason for this behavior? I am using activeperl on Windows and the version is 5.6.1.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

sub search
{
    return unless($File::Find::name =~ /\.h\s*$/);
    open (FH,"<", "$File::Find::name") or die "cannot open the file $File::Find::name  reason = $!";
    print "open success $File::Find::name\n";
    close FH;

}

sub fun
{
    open (FH,"<", "./tmp/tmp.h") or die "cannot open the file ./tmp/tmp.h  reason = $!";
    print "open success ./tmp/tmp.h\n";
    close FH;

}

find(\&search,".") ;
```

Comment: I just used your code, it works fine for me. Are you using some other code with this?

Comment: Two comments: Change the first line to 1) `return unless /\.h\s*$/` for brevity and clarity. Of course, you might want to do case insensitive matching as well and I am not sure why you want to accept trailing spaces after the file name. 2) No need to quote `$File::Find::name` in the `open` call.

Comment: And please, please use the three-argument call to open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [`perldoc File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html): The wanted function (search in your case) will be called after `File::Find::find` changed to the directory that is currently searched. As you can see, `$File::Find::name` contains the path to the file relative to where the search started. That path that won't work after the current directory changes.

You have two options:

1. Tell File::Find to not change to the directories it searches: `find( { wanted => \%search, no_chdir => 1 }, '.' );`
2. Or don't use `$File::Find::name`, but `$_` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If *./tmp/* is a symbolic link then you will need to do following:

```
find( { wanted => \&search, follow => 1 }, '.' );
```

Does that help?

Comment: He is on Windows. I doubt this has to do with symlinks.

Comment: Does open() work with forward slashes on Windows then?  Re: symlinks -  What about mounted UNIX/Linux share... will symlinks automatically be followed from Windows?

Comment: @draegtun Yes, `open` does work with forward slashes. `"tmp/tmp.h"` is preferred to `"tmp\\tmp.h"` (I prefer `File::Spec::catfile`). I do not know the answer to your second question.

Comment: @Sinan:  Thanks for info.   Its been nearly 10 years since I've used Perl on Windows!!   re: File::Spec... yes nice but I'll raise u Path::Class ;-)

Comment: @draegtun `Path::Class` wins! *how many people actually take the "volume" (like C: on Windows) into account when writing File::Spec-using code? I thought not.*

Answer (score -1):

If you want to search the file in current working dir you can use Cwd.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

my $dir = getcwd;

sub search
{
    return unless($File::Find::name =~ /\.h\s*$/);
    open (FH,"<", "$File::Find::name") or die "cannot open the file $File::Find::name  reason = $!";
    print "open success $File::Find::name\n";
    close FH;

}

find(\&search,"$dir") ;
```

Comment: This might actually work because getcwd will return an absolute path. But your answer sure requires a bit more explaining.